# looping through JSON data and inserting all bikestations into a dictionary

Tags: python, json

I am trying to loop through a JSON file and add data for all the bike stations listed into the dictionary instead of only the final bikestation, which is 502.  So if my code was working the way I want it to, The resulting dictionary would have JSON data for all 5 bikestations.  I am very new to this and any help is appreciated.  here is my code so far:

```
import json
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import datetime
import pymongo

stations = (123, 258, 290, 501, 502)

chicagoBikesURL =  "https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/eq45-8inv.json?"


for station in stations:
   paramD = dict()
   paramD["id"] = station
   paramD["$order"] = "timeStamp DESC"
   paramD["$limit"] = 2

   params = urllib.parse.urlencode(paramD)
   print(chicagoBikesURL+params)

   document = urllib.request.urlopen(chicagoBikesURL+params)
   # get all of the text from the document
   text = document.read().decode()
    
   if document.getcode() != 200 :
       print("Error code=",document.getcode(), chicagoBikesURL+params)
       text = "{}"

   # Load the JSON text from the URL into a dictionary using the json library
   js = json.loads(text)

   # Output first Record
   print("\nFirst BikeStation")
   print(js[0])

   # Write JSON data to a file
   fdumps = open('bike_data.txt', "w")
   fdumps.write(json.dumps(js).strip())
   bikeStation_list.append(js)
   # Make sure you close the file otherwise data may not be saved
   fdumps.close()

   #Process JSON Data
   bikeStation_list = []`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

`"w"` mode on the file open always creates a new file. So each one overwrites the previous so you will only see the final item.

To append to the file, use:

```
fdumps = open('bike_data.txt', "a")
```